# How do I download Resemble recording through Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use the Resemble library in Python to create an AI recording, but I cannot figure out how to save a recording.

```
from resemble import Resemble
Resemble.api_key('<MY API KEY>')

def create_recording():  
  voice_uuid = '58be67d5-701b-40aa-b796-e753fae53993'
  name = 'recording'
  text = 'This is a test'
  is_active = True
  emotion = 'neutral'
    
  with open("empty.wav", 'rb') as file:
    response = Resemble.v2.recordings.create(voice_uuid, file, name, text, is_active, emotion)
    recording = response['item']
    file.write(recording)

create_recording()
```

I keep getting "KeyError: 'item'" in recording = response['item'], but I can't figure out how to fix it, I have tried removing the ['item'] box, or changing 'item' to 'file', however it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the relevant api files, as follows:
`https://docs.app.resemble.ai/docs/resource_voice/create`
First of all, you should determine whether your request is successful, as follows

```py
if response['success']:
    recording = response['item']
```

Because if the response fails, there is no Item

Can `print(response)`

You can look at the returned information for further processing